# how to get string from url, assign it to an input text type and run the form

Tags: javascript

i was able to run this properly via googlechrome console without having the page to reload

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
jQuery('#addressInput').val(getParameterByName('addressInput'));
jQuery('#addressSubmit').click();
```

however i couldn't get it to run after i upload my .js file with this structure.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
getParameterByName(name);
jQuery('#addressInput').val(getParameterByName('addressInput'));
jQuery('#addressSubmit').click();

}

function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and i get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Any ideas how can i get this to run correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` for your `jQuery(document).ready()` block.

Comment: ops, i missed that one.. however i still didnt work after adding ');'

Comment: ... so what's your new error?

Comment: the only thing that isn't running is the .click();
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null [link]http://chemtools.circlebc.org.au/find/?addressInput=North+Bega%2C+NSW%2C+2550#searchForm

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#addressInput').val(getParameterByName('addressInput'));
jQuery('#addressSubmit').click();

});  // <-- close the bracket

function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: still didn't work, i updated the function to " getParameterByName(name)" but still no luck

Comment: fiddle if its possible...?

Comment: there is still a bug..getParameterByName(name); but name is not defined

Comment: this is want im trying to run onload [link](http://chemtools.circlebc.org.au/find/?addressInput=North+Bega%2C+NSW%2C+2550#searchForm)